# SOQL Relationship issues

Tags: soql, relationships

I am trying to write a SOQL query to pull out a number of items from 3 Objects - Contact, Account and Case.

I have the following code:

```
SELECT id, accountid, contactid, contact.primary_contact__c FROM case WHERE contact.Phone = '+6491234567' order by contact.primary_contact__c asc
```

Which returns a result if the Contact has an open Case related to them.

However, I'm trying to do an equivalent of a SQL Join - whereby I get NULL values and pulling from the Contact object:

```
SELECT id, accountid, primary_contact__c, (select id from case) FROM contact WHERE Phone = '+6491234567' order by primary_contact__c asc
```

(So the query will always return the ID of the Contact, the Account ID, etc. and if there is a case assigned against that contact, the case ID)

However the second query does not work - I know that the Relationships exist (otherwise the first query would not work) however, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the child relationship name is wrong in 2nd query, while writing inner query for case it should be like from **cases**, it should not be from **case**

I tried as below and it did work for me

> SELECT id, accountid, primary_contact__c, (select id from **cases**) FROM
>   contact WHERE Phone = '+6491234567' order by primary_contact__c asc

Comment: A Single 'S' - The cause of my frustration was a single 's' - thank you for the quick response - the above worked perfectly.